# Help proving: $∀x_1∀x_2∀x_3(x_1<x_2<x_3→f(x_1)<f(x_2)<f(x_3))$ implies $∀x∀x′(x<x′→f(x)<f(x′))$ on the $\mathbb N$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Suppose I know the following:

> $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \forall x_3 \Big(x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3 \rightarrow f(x_1) \lt f(x_2) \lt f(x_3) \Big) \quad (\dagger_1)$

Could someone please explain, step by step, how I can justify bringing the following statement into my argument:

> $\forall x \forall x' \Big (x \lt x' \rightarrow f(x) \lt f(x') \Big) \quad (\dagger_2)$

**To begin with, let the domain be $\mathbb R$**.

---

**ARGUMENT:**

Consider an arbitrary $x$ and $x'$ where $x \lt x'$. Because we are in $\mathbb R$, I know that there exists an $x^*$ such that $x \lt x^* \lt x'$ (e.g. $x^*=\frac{x+x'}{2}$). Therefore, I can apply $(\dagger_1)$ to assert that $f(x) \lt f(x^*) \lt f(x')$. But, by transitivity, I have $f(x) \lt f(x')$.

As such: $\forall x \forall x' \Big (x \lt x' \rightarrow f(x) \lt f(x') \Big)$

---

Now, where I get a little confused is when, instead of $\mathbb R$, **we let the domain be $\mathbb N$** (or $\mathbb Z$). My argument no longer works because we cannot be guaranteed that a number exists between two natural numbers (e.g. there is no number between $2$ and $3$).

However, intuitively, I feel like $(\dagger_1)$ should imply $(\dagger_2)$ *even if* we are in $\mathbb N$ (if not, what is the counter example?). Given this, I would think that there must be a more generalizable argument than the one I provided. If someone could provide that argument, I would greatly appreciate it!

---

**INITIAL THOUGHTS:**

$(\dagger_1)$ is more formally written as:

> $\forall x_1 \forall x_2 \forall x_3 \Big(x_1 \lt x_2 \land x_2 \lt x_3 \rightarrow f(x_1) \lt f(x_2) \land f(x_2) \lt f(x_3) \Big)$

The general form would then be something like:

> $\forall x \forall y \forall z \Big(\varphi(x,y) \land \varphi(y,z) \rightarrow \psi(x,y) \land \psi (y,z) \Big)$

Because of transitivity of $\lt$, I see that I can produce the following statements:

> $\varphi(x,y) \land \varphi (y,z) \rightarrow \varphi (x,z)$

> $\psi(x,y) \land \psi(y,z) \rightarrow \psi (x,z)$

> Therefore, $\forall x \forall y \forall z\Big(\varphi(x,y) \land \varphi(y,z) \rightarrow \varphi(x,z) \land \psi(x,z)\Big)$

I am not really sure what to do from here.

Comment: If it is true for $x_1<x_2<x_3$ and you want to prove it for $x<x'$ just take $x_1=x, x_2 = x'$, and $x_3$ any number above $x_2$, say $x_2 + 1$. (Note that if this course is not in logics then the step above is likely meant to be obvious without the need to write this formal justification)

Comment: @Snaw Ahh, yes. Silly on my end. Thank you.

Comment: @Snaw Would it be appropriate to say that $$\Big(\forall y \exists z :\varphi(y,z) \Big)\rightarrow \color{red}{\Big(}\big[ \forall x \forall y \forall z \big(\varphi(x,y) \land \varphi(y,z) \rightarrow \psi(x,y) \land \psi (y,z) \big)\big] \rightarrow \big[ \forall x\forall y \big(\varphi(x,y) \rightarrow\psi(x,y) \big)\big]\color{red}{\Big)}$$

Comment: Given that I parsed that correctly it seems true, because given $(x,y)$ which satisfy $\varphi(x,y)$ and we want them to satisfy $\psi(x,y)$, then the middle term will help us if we can show that there is some $z$ for which $\phi(y,z)$ is true, and the initial term guarantees that this $z$ exists.

Comment: Aye: the big formula in the above comment is indeed valid.